# Programs for reading data off interactive web charts

Tags: images, charts, interactive, screen-scraping

This question is in the same vein as this one: [Program for reading data off scanned graphs](https://superuser.com/questions/93639/program-for-reading-data-off-scanned-graphs)

Recently more and more interactive charts show up on the Net. Have a look at the following one:

http://www.finanzen.net/zertifikate/zertifikate_emittenten_detail.asp?inEmNr=47

**My question**
Is there a possibility of automatically reading out the data into a table? Are there some tools available because I can't find the data in the source code? There should be a solution because if you point to the curve you'll get all the data.

Comment: There's no generic solution for that. The graph itself is SVG-based, so you can download the source and try to play around with the raw curves and all that though.

Comment: @slhck: Can you expound on this and make an answer out of it? cheers vonjd

Comment: I don't feel too comfortable doing that, since it's not a real answer. I looked into the source code a little more and it seems the whole data is [contained here](http://www.finanzen.net/stockchart/export.asp?stSId=1&stIT=1&stIId=291&stDtFrom=04.04.1997&stDtTo=11.07.2012&stIntraday=0&stV=&stB=&stW=&stC=0&sign_ts=1342025438&sign=a77ce23634621f450781472accf8dded) – but encoded.

Comment: When I click on the link nothing happens?

Comment: Oh, it seems it's timed out already, sorry. They seem to dynamically generate it then.

Comment: Isn't it ironic that humans can read the data bit by bit but machines not...?