# Manually "draw" data for chart, output to CSV

Tags: charts, csv

I need a service that will allow me to draw a chart line **by hand** and generate data points for what I drew. This might sound crazy, but I need some data (preferably in CSV output) that will only approximately show value X at time Y and I do not want to go and produce these values by hand. I only have to know how it will flow along. Anyone know how to actually accomplish this?

So, I would actually want to draw a line on a graph, and then get the output (X + Y) from that line I drew in a (preferably) CSV.

Comment: This is common in CAD software where complex curvy geometry sometimes need to be approximated as a series of points connected by a spline... But that's the only place I've run across this functionality.

Comment: You may get somewhere with a tool like Visio ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599855/visio-coordinates-format

Answer (score 2):

Check out this previous superuser answer: ["Program for reading data off scanned graphs"](https://superuser.com/a/93642/101700).

See also the Wikipedia page on [Converting scanned graphs to data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converting_scanned_graphs_to_data). Below is the list of software on that page:

> - DataThief III is Java standalone software to digitize plots.
> - Engauge Digitizer is an open source digitizing software available for Linux and Windows. Latest release in 2007.
> - Plot Digitizer is an open source Java program for digitizing scanned plots. It is available for a number of platforms. Actively developed
>     as of November 2011.
> - g3data is open source graph digitizer based on GTK+. Last release in 2011.
> - Silk Scientific, Inc. www.silkscientific.com offers proprietary graph digitizing software such as Un-scan-it
> - DigitizeIt is a proprietary digitizer.
> - Graphics software FindGraph from UNIPHYZ Lab contains digitizing capability.
> - General graphics package ORIGIN (proprietary) includes tools for digitization.
> - GetData Graph Digitizer is a proprietary standalone software to digitize plots.
> - Dagra, a proprietary program for Microsoft Windows, uses Bezier curves to digitize  graphs.
> - OmniGraphSketcher, a proprietary Macintosh application, allows interactive point selection from graphics displayed on screen (via a
>     transparent window).
> - XYit Image Digitizer (proprietary) from Geomatix, for graphs, maps and charts
> - WebPlotDigitizer is a good online graph digitizing tool.

Answer (score 1):

I like WebPlotDigitizer
https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/

Flexible, simple, yet has everything I need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [im2graph](Http://www.im2graph.co.il), a digitizing software to convert graph-images to graph-data, that is to numbers (e.g. CSV). It is available on Linux and Windows (future versions will include MacOS) and is free for personal use.
Disclaimer: I wrote the software
- Shai

Comment: It might be useful to look at this link on software recommendations to avoid being dinged: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers